# Read in .csv stored in Google Drive for Desktop into R

Tags: r, google-drive-api

I am trying to migrate from Google Drive Sync and Backup to the new Google Drive for Desktop application. I used to be able to enter a file path of a .csv stored locally in a Google sync folder in Rstudio, and I could easily read in my data. Now, Google has changed their local storage system, and I can't find the correct way to enter that file path into R. I am using a Macbook running 10.14.6. Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `googledrive` package?

Comment: I have used it some, but I prefer to treat drive as a local folder instead of connecting to online storage.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer with the help of this SO post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60231/using-terminal-how-can-i-find-which-directory-is-my-usb-drive-mounted-in

Google Drive for Desktop appears as a removable disk. Using the terminal for Mac, you can find where the directory is mounted by using the `mount` command. Instead of the usual "/Users/Google Drive/myFilepath.csv" in `read.csv()`, Drive for Desktop is stored in "/Volumes/GoogleDrive".